MongoDb not deleting a record by _id, deletedCount: 0
We have a collection in MongoDB (Atlas), where _id is a String uuid refering to some external entity.
Then there's a process which select a list of records (based on time, whatever), process them and then attempts to remove the records.
   // "results" contains a list of records previously fetched from the db colleaction

   const deleteResults = await Promise.all(results
       .map(result => removeExpiredPayload(result._id, collection)))
        .catch(e => { throw e });
   console.log(deleteResults);

  const removeExpiredPayload = (_id, collection) => {
    console.log(`Removing event _id "${_id}"`)
    return collection.deleteOne({ _id });
  }


Yet - there are occasional (and not rare) cases, where MongoDB returns deletedCount as 0, even the record was found and processed. And the record stays in the DB collection.
logs:
Removing event _id "10f94444-fb52-4196-9b2f-802408312345"
Removing event _id "c3d45555-de06-4bee-b8bb-de690b543210"

[
  { acknowledged: true, deletedCount: 1 },
  { acknowledged: true, deletedCount: 0 }
]

Can MongoDB just ignore or refuse the delete request? Any idea why and what can be done about it?

Can you try to modify the call to use deleteMany to see if the same issue persists? It can help to isolate the problem from node.js issue or MongoDB issue. And, actually deleteMany helps you to save DB round trips and you may want to switch to that for more performance.
